# PostgresSQL SETPGPASSWORD not setting password

Tags: windows, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to push to Heroku and I got the password prompt with the wrong user like many people, so I went and did

```
SET PGUSER=[pg_username]

SET PGPASSWORD=[pg_password]
```

I am putting in the command:

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb DATABASE_URL --app my-app
```

It changed the username but the password didn't work and I get the error message:

```
connection to database "mylocaldb" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Janet"
```

How do I change/find the password?

my pg_hba file looks like this :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             [redacted]            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             [redacted]               md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             [redacted]           trust
host    replication     all             [redacted]               trust
```

Comment: Have you enabled password authentication for the user Janet in your local Postgres? I think it uses [`trust`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html) out of the box.

Comment: I think I did.  I added my pg_hba file to the main post.  It is still giving me the same errors.

Comment: And you can log in using the password via `psql` or another client? Does the password have any strange characters in it? You can try quoting it, e.g. `SET PGPASSWORD='MY_PASSWORD!$?'`.

Comment: I tried an all lowercase password and I tried all lowercase in quotes as well.  The one I originally set it to had an uppercase and an !.

I can connect and do everything else just fine with heroku and postgres.  The weird thing is the username it pops up as is the username of my computer, which I don't use anywhere else.  I tried my windows password and my postgres password and neither of them worked.  When I go to change the username it will change the username no problem, but not the password.